# Keys like TAB and KEY_UP don't work as expected (e.g. KEY_UP becomes "^[[A") in PTY program

Tags: c, sh, pty

I have a pty code example,(probably the most popular pty example) I am trying to use it to start sh [shell terminal] in the slave but the hotkeys such as cd  or key up [last command] not working [does nothing]
I compile it with `gcc -o pty.o pty.c`
and run `./pty.o "sh"`
but when I try to do up key it's just print  `^[[A` and tab do tab indent and not  suggestion directory option's  .
the code  are in http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html :

under mypty3:

> We can make mypty2 more generic in order to be able to execute any program behind the pty (slave side). In mypty3, the father process writes **all the data** from its standard input to the master side of the pty and writes all the data from the master side of the pty to its standard output. The child process behaves the same as in mypty2 but executes an interactive program along with its parameters passed as arguments to the program. We can note the calls to `setsid()` and `ioctl(TIOCSCTTY)` to make the pty be the control terminal of the executed program. We can also note the closing of the `fds` file descriptor which becomes useless after the calls to `dup()`.

```
 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define __USE_BSD
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
int fdm, fds;
int rc;
char input[150];

// Check arguments
if (ac <= 1)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s program_name [parameters]\n", av[0]);
exit(1);
}

fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
if (fdm < 0)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on posix_openpt()\n", errno);
return 1;
}

rc = grantpt(fdm);
if (rc != 0)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on grantpt()\n", errno);
return 1;
}

rc = unlockpt(fdm);
if (rc != 0)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on unlockpt()\n", errno);
return 1;
}

// Open the slave side ot the PTY
fds = open(ptsname(fdm), O_RDWR);

// Create the child process
if (fork())
{
fd_set fd_in;

  // FATHER

  // Close the slave side of the PTY
  close(fds);

  while (1)
  {
    // Wait for data from standard input and master side of PTY
    FD_ZERO(&fd_in);
    FD_SET(0, &fd_in);
    FD_SET(fdm, &fd_in);

    rc = select(fdm + 1, &fd_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    switch(rc)
    {
      case -1 : fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on select()\n", errno);
                exit(1);

      default :
      {
        // If data on standard input
        if (FD_ISSET(0, &fd_in))
        {
          rc = read(0, input, sizeof(input));
          if (rc > 0)
          {
            // Send data on the master side of PTY
            write(fdm, input, rc);
          }
          else
          {
            if (rc < 0)
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read standard input\n", errno);
              exit(1);
            }
          }
        }

        // If data on master side of PTY
        if (FD_ISSET(fdm, &fd_in))
        {
          rc = read(fdm, input, sizeof(input));
          if (rc > 0)
          {
            // Send data on standard output
            write(1, input, rc);
          }
          else
          {
            if (rc < 0)
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read master PTY\n", errno);
              exit(1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } // End switch
  } // End while
}
else
{
struct termios slave_orig_term_settings; // Saved terminal settings
struct termios new_term_settings; // Current terminal settings

  // CHILD

  // Close the master side of the PTY
  close(fdm);

  // Save the defaults parameters of the slave side of the PTY
  rc = tcgetattr(fds, &slave_orig_term_settings);

  // Set RAW mode on slave side of PTY
  new_term_settings = slave_orig_term_settings;
  cfmakeraw (&new_term_settings);
  tcsetattr (fds, TCSANOW, &new_term_settings);

  // The slave side of the PTY becomes the standard input and outputs of the child process
  close(0); // Close standard input (current terminal)
  close(1); // Close standard output (current terminal)
  close(2); // Close standard error (current terminal)

  dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard input (0)
  dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard output (1)
  dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard error (2)

  // Now the original file descriptor is useless
  close(fds);

  // Make the current process a new session leader
  setsid();

  // As the child is a session leader, set the controlling terminal to be the slave side of the PTY
  // (Mandatory for programs like the shell to make them manage correctly their outputs)
  ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 1);

  // Execution of the program
  {
  char **child_av;
  int i;

    // Build the command line
    child_av = (char **)malloc(ac * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 1; i < ac; i ++)
    {
      child_av[i - 1] = strdup(av[i]);
    }
    child_av[i - 1] = NULL;
    rc = execvp(child_av[0], child_av);
  }

  // if Error...
  return 1;
}

return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cfmakeraw()` should be called in the parent process rather than in the child process. Then all user inputs (<kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, ...) would be handled by the child process. And the parent needs to restore its original terminal setting before exiting.

Updated code (1. moved `cfmakeraw()` from child to parent; 2. restore terminal setting before `exit()`):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>

struct termios save_termios;

void restore_term(void)
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &save_termios);
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int fdm, fds;
    int rc;
    char input[150];

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, & save_termios);

    // Check arguments
    if (ac <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s program_name [parameters]\n", av[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
    if (fdm < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on posix_openpt()\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    rc = grantpt(fdm);
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on grantpt()\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    rc = unlockpt(fdm);
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on unlockpt()\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the slave side ot the PTY
    fds = open(ptsname(fdm), O_RDWR);

    // Create the child process
    if (fork())
    {
        fd_set fd_in;
        struct termios new_setting;

        // FATHER
        atexit(restore_term);

        new_setting = save_termios;
        cfmakeraw ( & new_setting);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, & new_setting);

        // Close the slave side of the PTY
        close(fds);

        while (1)
        {
            // Wait for data from standard input and master side of PTY
            FD_ZERO(&fd_in);
            FD_SET(0, &fd_in);
            FD_SET(fdm, &fd_in);

            rc = select(fdm + 1, &fd_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            switch(rc)
            {
            case -1 : fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on select()\n", errno);
                      exit(1);

            default :
                      {
                          // If data on standard input
                          if (FD_ISSET(0, &fd_in))
                          {
                              rc = read(0, input, sizeof(input));
                              if (rc > 0)
                              {
                                  // Send data on the master side of PTY
                                  write(fdm, input, rc);
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  if (rc < 0)
                                  {
                                      fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read standard input\n", errno);
                                      exit(1);
                                  }
                              }
                          }

                          // If data on master side of PTY
                          if (FD_ISSET(fdm, &fd_in))
                          {
                              rc = read(fdm, input, sizeof(input));
                              if (rc > 0)
                              {
                                  // Send data on standard output
                                  write(1, input, rc);
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  if (rc < 0)
                                  {
                                      fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read master PTY\n", errno);
                                      exit(1);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
            } // End switch
        } // End while
    }
    else
    {
        // CHILD

        // Close the master side of the PTY
        close(fdm);

        // The slave side of the PTY becomes the standard input and outputs of the child process
        close(0); // Close standard input (current terminal)
        close(1); // Close standard output (current terminal)
        close(2); // Close standard error (current terminal)

        dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard input (0)
        dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard output (1)
        dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard error (2)

        // Now the original file descriptor is useless
        close(fds);

        // Make the current process a new session leader
        setsid();

        // As the child is a session leader, set the controlling terminal to be the slave side of the PTY
        // (Mandatory for programs like the shell to make them manage correctly their outputs)
        ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 1);

        // Execution of the program
        {
            char **child_av;
            int i;

            // Build the command line
            child_av = (char **)malloc(ac * sizeof(char *));
            for (i = 1; i < ac; i ++)
            {
                child_av[i - 1] = strdup(av[i]);
            }
            child_av[i - 1] = NULL;
            rc = execvp(child_av[0], child_av);
        }

        // if Error...
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: i have tried to commeect this in the child and in the father do            :// Open the slave side ot the PTY
fds = open(ptsname(fdm), O_RDWR);

// Create the child process
if (fork())
{
fd_set fd_in;

  // FATHER
  struct termios slave_orig_term_settings; // Saved terminal settings

  tcgetattr(fds, &slave_orig_term_settings);
cfmakeraw (&slave_orig_term_settings); it did not work , what to intizlize the  termios structure that send to cfmakeraw?

Comment: pasted code in the answer. tested on debian9 and it worked fine for me. give it a try.

Comment: this code work's for me too [on Ubnutu 16.4 ], thank's a lot